# How to add class to <ul> and childs <li> of sidebar widget - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is how I register the menus on my right sidebar:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
  register_sidebar(array(
            'name'=>'sidebar_default',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-info">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="panel-heading"><h4>',
            'after_title' => '</h4></div>'
        ));
 }
```

And this is the output:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Title</h4>
   </div>
<div class="menu-openings-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-openings-menu" class="menu">
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-381"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-382"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-383"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-384"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-385"><a href="">Software</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is how do it need the output to be able to use Twitter Bootstrap list-styles styles:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate all suggestions. Thanks.

[image: output]

[image: Source code]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WordPress function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), you can just add a `'class' => 'list-group',` property to your passed options, like this:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=>'sidebar_default',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-info">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="panel-heading"><h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4></div>',
        'class' => 'list-group'
    ));
}
```

This should set the class of the `ul`.
I'm not sure if you can also set the class for the individual `li`'s, but those can be accessed through the `ul`
(`ul.list-group li` in css)

Answer (score 0):

This is only for backend :(

```
    class - CSS class to assign to the Sidebar in the Appearance -> Widget admin page. This class will only appear in the source of the WordPress Widget admin page. It will not be included in the frontend of your website. Note: The value "sidebar" will be prepended to the class value. For example, a class of "tal" will result in a class value of "sidebar-tal". (default: empty).
before_widget - HTML to place before every widget(default: '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">') Note: uses sprintf for variable substitution
```